# Placeholder in Vuetify <v-select> tag not working

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I've tried searching for a solution but haven't found one yet. 
I have a Vuetify [v-select](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects) dropdown for **start time** and another for **end time**.

Once the user selects a time, I want it to show a `placeholder` - show *"start time"* and *"end time"* in the corner of the selection in small. (So the user should know what field it is) Setting the `placeholder` attribute didn't seem to help.

**HTML**

```
<!--placeholder not working on v-select>-->
    <v-select
      :items="getTimes"
      label="Start Time"
      prepend-icon="access_time"
      solo
      placeholder="Start Time"
    ></v-select>

    <v-select
      :items="getTimes"
      label="End Time"
      solo
      placeholder="End Time"
    ></v-select>
    </v-layout> `
```

**JS**

```
computed:
{
  getTimes()
  {
    this.hour=0;
    this.min=0;
    this.twelveHourTime=0;

    for(this.hour=6; this.hour<=22; this.hour++)
    {
         for(this.min=0;this.min<=45;this.min+=15)
        {

           //move to 12 hr time and add am's and pm's

            if (this.hour>12)
            {
               this.twelveHourTime = this.hour-12;
               this.setPeriod="pm";
            }
          else
          {
           this.twelveHourTime = this.hour;
              if(this.hour==12)
              {
                this.setPeriod = "pm";
              }
              else
              {
                this.setPeriod = "am";
              }

          }

             //add the time options to times array

            if (this.min==0)
            {
               this.times.push(this.twelveHourTime + ":00 " + this.setPeriod);
            }
            else
            {
             this.times.push(this.twelveHourTime + ":" + this.min + " " + this.setPeriod );
            }
        }
    }


     return this.times;
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course the `placeholder` prop will not work because you have **solo** as prop. Remove it or change it to other style like **box** or **outline** it will show.

Another point, if your `getTimes()` function is to have pre-loaded data then it belongs to `methods` not the `computed` hook. Just pass the data property `times` (array) to the `:items` prop in the `<v-select>`.

*Suggestion: You could also change `<v-select>` to `<v-autocomplete>` for better user experience. With the first you have to drag the scrollbar while the latter it autocompletes while typing.*

You code could look output like this

**Codepen**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JBxMzW?&editors=101

**HTML**

```
 <v-layout>

    <v-select
      :items="times"
      label="Start Time"
      prepend-icon="access_time"
      box
      placeholder="Start Time"
   ></v-select>
   <v-select
     :items="times"
     label="End Time"
     box
     placeholder="End Time"
   ></v-select>
</v-layout>
```

**JS**

```
 data() {
    return {
        hour: 0,
        min: 0,
        twelveHourTime: 0,
        setPeriod: '',
        times: []
    }
},

mounted() {
  this.getTimes()
},

methods:{
  getTimes()
    {
        this.hour=0;
        this.min=0;
        this.twelveHourTime=0;

        for(this.hour=6; this.hour<=22; this.hour++)
        {
            for(this.min=0;this.min<=45;this.min+=15)
            {

            //move to 12 hr time and add am's and pm's

                if (this.hour>12)
                {
                this.twelveHourTime = this.hour-12;
                this.setPeriod="pm";
                }
            else
            {
            this.twelveHourTime = this.hour;
                if(this.hour==12)
                {
                    this.setPeriod = "pm";
                }
                else
                {
                    this.setPeriod = "am";
                }

            }
                //add the time options to times array

                if (this.min==0)
                {
                this.times.push(this.twelveHourTime + ":00 " + this.setPeriod);
                }
                else
                {
                this.times.push(this.twelveHourTime + ":" + this.min + " " + this.setPeriod );
                }
            }
        }
        return this.times;
    }
}
```